# Should I use a Shebang with Bash scripts?

Tags: bash, shell, sh, shebang

I am using Bash

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

and starting about a year ago I stopped using Shebangs with my Bash scripts. Can
I benefit from using `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash`?

Update: In certain situations a file is only treated as a script with the
Shebang, example

```
$ cat foo.sh
ls

$ cat bar.sh
#!/bin/sh
ls

$ file foo.sh bar.sh
foo.sh: ASCII text
bar.sh: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable
```

Comment: I think you can benefit from using `#!/bin/bash` if you run your script on another machine. If that machine uses a default shell different from Bash, you can be sure that your script will run with the intended shell.

Comment: I guess the shebang line is good if you're running a non-POSIX shell by default but want to ensure that the script is actually executed in a POSIX compatible shell (or vice versa, you're using features inside your script that aren't POSIX default, you can only ensure that the script will run fine even if started from a POSIX shell like bash). So in your case, there won't be any difference.

Comment: Always, always, always. If you don't use a shebang line, you're not just making your script needlessly unportable, you're preventing it from running at all in a fairly wide array of circumstances.

Comment: See http://homepages.cwi.nl/~aeb/std/hashexclam-1.html#ss1.1 and http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/ for more details than you want to know about the history and portability of various shebang line details.

Comment: I can't find them at the moment but I know I was involved with at least two questions on this site about errors from shell scripts that resulted from a bash-specific script being executed by `dash` or `sh` instead because of a lack of specification (like a shebang line provides).

Comment: The fact that `SHELL` is `/bin/bash` says nothing about which shell you are using.  If you execute `csh`, it will not change SHELL.  You can `eval ksh`, or `eval zsh`, or `csh -c zsh`, and SHELL will retain its value (unless the startup scripts for a particular shell change it, which they really ought not do).  Demonstrating the value of SHELL says *nothing* about which shell you are using.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

On UNIX-like systems, you should *always* start scripts with a shebang line. The system call `execve` (which is responsible for starting programs) *relies* on an executable having either an executable header or a shebang line.

From FreeBSD's [execve manual page](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=execve&sektion=2):

> ```
>  The execve() system call transforms the calling process into a new
>  process.  The new process is constructed from an ordinary file, whose
>  name is pointed to by path, called the new process file.
>  [...]
>
>  This file is
>  either an executable object file, or a file of data for an interpreter.
>
>  [...]
>
>  An interpreter file begins with a line of the form:
>
>        #! interpreter [arg]
>
>  When an interpreter file is execve'd, the system actually execve's the
>  specified interpreter.  If the optional arg is specified, it becomes the
>  first argument to the interpreter, and the name of the originally
>  execve'd file becomes the second argument
> ```

Similarly from the [Linux manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve):

> execve() executes the program pointed to by filename. filename must be
>   either a binary executable, or a script starting with a line of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> #! interpreter [optional-arg]
> ```

In fact, if a file doesn't have the right "magic number" in it's header, (like an ELF header or `#!`), `execve` will *fail* with the ENOEXEC error (again from FreeBSD's execve manpage):

> [ENOEXEC]  The new process file has the appropriate access 
>              permission, but has an invalid magic number in its
>              header.

---

If the file has executable permissions, but no shebang line but does seem to be a text file, the behaviour depends on the shell that you're running in.

Most shells seem to start a new instance of themselves and feed it the file, see below.

Since there is no guarantee that the script was actually written for that shell, this can work or fail spectacularly.

From [tcsh(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?tcsh):

> ```
>    On  systems which do not understand the `#!' script interpreter conven‐
>    tion the shell may be compiled to emulate it;  see  the  version  shell
>    variable.  If so, the shell checks the first line of the file to see if
>    it is of the form `#!interpreter arg ...'.  If it is, the shell  starts
>    interpreter  with  the  given args and feeds the file to it on standard
>    input.
> ```

From FreeBSD's [sh(1)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sh):

```
If the program is not a normal executable file (i.e., if it
     does not begin with the “magic number” whose ASCII representation is
     “#!”, resulting in an ENOEXEC return value from execve(2)) but appears to
     be a text file, the shell will run a new instance of sh to interpret it.
```

From bash(1):

> ```
>    If this execution fails because the file is not in  executable  format,
>    and  the file is not a directory, it is assumed to be a shell script, a
>    file containing shell commands.  A subshell is spawned to  execute  it.
> ```

---

You cannot always depend on the location of a non-standard program like bash. I've seen bash in `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, `/opt/fsf/bin` and `/opt/gnu/bin` to name a few.

So it is generally a good idea to use `env`;

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

If you want your script to be portable, use `sh` instead of `bash`.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
```

While standards like POSIX do *not guarantee* the absolute paths of standard utilities, most UNIX-like systems seem to have `sh` in `/bin` and `env` in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: There are arguments for and against the `#!/usr/bin/env` hack. See [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/29608/10454) and [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29620/10454).

Comment: "most" != "all". You are ruling out one of the most deployed commercial Unix by assuming `/bin/sh` is a POSIX compliant shell.

Comment: Having a `/bin/sh` is pretty common. I'm not assuming `sh` is POSIX compliant.

Comment: This somewhat contradict "If you want your script to be portable". The script will indeed start whatever the platform as /bin/sh is there, but the script might fail or behave differently at least on Solaris 10 and olders, as the SVR4 Bourne shell is lacking some features most script developers expects will work.

Comment: My remark was in the context that these days common assumptions are that UNIX means GNU/Linux and a shell means `bash`.

Comment: It's worth noting that [shebang is only required for executable scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7615477/9157799).

Answer (score 15):

Scripts should always begin with a shebang line. If a script doesn't start with this, then it may be executed by the current shell. But that means that if someone who uses your script is running a different shell than you do, the script may behave differently. Also, it means the script can't be run directly from a program (e.g. the C `exec()` system call, or `find -exec`), it has to be run from a shell.

Comment: Absent a shebang, most(?) OSes will try to execute a script using the system shell.

Comment: I guess it's changed over time and between OSes.

Comment: "the system shell" is the dangerous part of @chepner's comment and the exact reason why you should use one, which is the OP's question.

Comment: Without a shebang, scripts will be executed by `/bin/sh`, which could be any of several different Bourne-like shells. Depending on the system, it might be a symlink to `dash`, `bash`, or `ksh`, for example.

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure that they're *guaranteed* to be executed by `/bin/sh`. The `#!` method is not standardized by POSIX (to my surprise).

Comment: Without a shebang, the script will be executed by the POSIX shell (either directly or through `find -exec`) when you are in a POSIX environment running in a POSIX platform. The POSIX shell doesn't need and is not guaranteed to be `/bin/sh`. Specifying this PATH breaks portability in at least one well known and still commonly used commercial Unix platform so shouldn't be hardcoded by a shebang.

Comment: If the script without a shebang line is started from a shell, most shells start a copy of themselves and feed it the file. See the manpage references in my answer below.

Comment: @RolandSmith That's what I wrote in my second sentence: _it may be executed by the current shell_.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in an [early description](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/shebang/sys1.c.html) by Dennis M Ritchie (`dmr`) who invented the `#!` :

> From uucp Thu Jan 10 01:37:58 1980
>
> .>From dmr Thu Jan 10 04:25:49 1980 remote from research
>
> The system has been changed so that if a file
>   being executed begins with the magic characters #! , the rest of the
>   line is understood to be the name of an interpreter for the executed
>   file. Previously (and in fact still) the shell did much of this job;
>   it automatically executed itself on a text file with executable mode
>   when the text file's name was typed as a command. Putting the facility
>   into the system gives the following benefits.
>
> 1) It makes shell scripts more like real executable files, because
>   they can be the subject of 'exec.'
>
> 2) If you do a 'ps' while such a command is running, its real name
>   appears instead of 'sh'. Likewise, accounting is done on the basis of
>   the real name.
>
> 3) Shell scripts can be set-user-ID.
>
> 4) It is simpler to have alternate shells available; e.g. if you like
>   the Berkeley csh there is no question about which shell is to
>   interpret a file.
>
> 5) It will allow other interpreters to fit in more smoothly.
>
> To take advantage of this wonderful opportunity, put
>
> ```
>    #! /bin/sh
> ```
>
> at the left margin of the first line of your shell scripts. Blanks
>   after ! are OK.  Use a complete pathname (no search is done). At the
>   moment the whole line is restricted to 16 characters but this limit
>   will be raised.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think the line length restriction was also raised a while back. However, I believe most implementations limit it to one argument in the shebang line.

Comment: I should have state more clearly that it was the description from 1980 (despite the link). I edit for that. Note that this answer was aimed at providing some historical perspectives about what was `#!` invented for.

Comment: @StevenPenny Unfortunately I don't have other information than what can be found in the other answers.

Answer (score 3):

- If you write **bash** scripts, i.e. non portable scripts containing bashisms, you should keep using the `#!/bin/bash` shebang just to be sure the correct interpreter is used. You should not replace the shebang by `#!/bin/sh` as bash will run in POSIX mode so some of your scripts might behave differently.
- If you write **portable** scripts, i.e. scripts only using POSIX utilities and their supported options, you might keep using `#!/bin/sh` on *your* system (i.e. one where `/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell).
- It you write **stricly conforming POSIX scripts** to be distributed in various platforms and you are sure they will only be launched from a POSIX conforming system, you might and probably should remove the shebang as stated in the POSIX standard:

[As it stands, a strictly conforming application must not use "#!" as the first two characters of the file.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_01)

The rationale is the POSIX standard doesn't mandate `/bin/sh` to be the POSIX compliant shell so there is no portable way to specify its path in a shebang. In this third case, to be able to use the 'find -exec' syntax on systems unable to run a shebangless still executable script, you can simply specify the interpreter in the find command itself, eg:

```
find /tmp -name "*.foo" -exec sh -c 'myscript "$@"' sh {} +
```

Here, as `sh` is specified without a path, the POSIX shell will be run.

Comment: As I understand it, POSIX doesn't even specify that `#!` causes it to run an interpreter at all. Everything about shebang is a _de facto_ standard, not part of the official specification.

Comment: @StevenPenny  In a posix conforming environment, the first `sh` tells `find` to run the POSIX shell as it is guaranteed to be the first one found in the PATH. The second `sh` is setting `$0`, it could be almost anything but `sh` makes sense for a shell. `{} +` is filling the potential remaining arguments ($1, $2, ...) that will be passed to the `myscript` command.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**: always in scripts; please not in `source`'d scripts

- **Always in your parent**

  FYI: POSIX compliant is `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`

  You want to clarify this so that nothing else overrides the interpreter your script is made for.

  - You don't want a user at the terminal using  `zsh` to have trouble if your script was written for POSIX `bash` scripts.
  - You don't want to run `source` in your `#!/bin/bash` unrecognized by `#!/bin/sh`, someone in an `sh` terminal have it break the script because it is expecting the simple/POSIX `.` for including `source`'d files
  - You don't want e.g. `zsh` features - not available in other interpreters - to make their way into your `bash` code. So, put `#!/bin/bash` in all your script headers. Then, any of your `zsh` habits in your script will break so you know to remove them before your roll-out.

  It's probably best, especially so POSIX-compliant scripts don't break in a terminal like `zsh`.
- **Not expected for included `source` scripts**

  FYI: POSIX compliant for sourcing text in a BASH script is `.`, not `source`

  You can use either for sourcing, but I'll do POSIX.

  Standard "shebanging" for all scripting:

  **parent.sh**:

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash

  echo "My script here"

  . sourced.sh # child/source script, below
  ```

  **sourced.sh**:

  ```bash
  echo "I am a sourced child script"
  ```

  But, you are allowed to do this...

  **sourced.sh**: (optional)

  ```bash
  #!/bin/bash
  echo "I am a sourced child script"
  ```

  There, the `#!/bin/bash` "shebang" will be ignored. The main reason I would use it is for syntax highlighting in my text editor. However, in the "proper" scripting world, it is expected that your rolled-out `source`'d script will not contain the shebang.

Comment: FYI: bash _also_ has features/syntax that are not baseline POSIX.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oh, for sure, such as `source` as I wrote.

Comment: This answer was made in lieu of the comments on the [SO meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/418503/what-to-do-about-this-special-dup-bash-script-vs-bash-include#comment913541_418503)

Answer (score 1):

The header is useful since it specifies which shell to use when running the script. For example, `#!/bin/zsh` would change the shell to zsh instead of bash, where you can use different commands.

For example, [this page](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sha-bang.html) specifies the following:

> Using #!/bin/sh, the default Bourne shell in most commercial variants
>   of UNIX, makes the script portable to non-Linux machines, though you
>   sacrifice Bash-specific features ...

Answer (score 0):

$SHELL and #!/bin/bash or #!/bin/sh are different.

To start, #!/bin/sh is a symlink to /bin/bash on most Linux systems (on Ubuntu it is now /bin/dash)

But on whether to start with /bin/sh or /bin/bash:

> Bash and sh are two different shells. Basically bash is sh, with more
>   features and better syntax. Most commands work the same, but they are
>   different.

Just assume if you're writing a bash script, stick with /bin/bash and not /sh because problems can arise.

> $SHELL does not necessarily reflect the currently running shell.
>   Instead, $SHELL is the user's preferred shell, which is typically the
>   one set in /etc/passwd. If you start a different shell after logging
>   in, you can not necessarily expect $SHELL to match the current shell
>   anymore.

This is mine for example, but it could also be /root:/bin/dash or /root:/bin/sh depending on which shell you have input in passwd. So to avoid any problems, keep the passwd file at /bin/bash and then using $SHELL vs. #!/bin/bash wouldn't matter as much.

```
root@kali:~/Desktop# cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```

Sources:
http://shebang.mintern.net/bourne-is-not-bash-or-read-echo-and-backslash/
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43499/difference-between-echo-shell-and-which-bash
http://man.cx/sh
http://man.cx/bash

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what the others said, the shebang also enables syntax highlighting in some text editors, for example vim.