# subprocess.call not working from pyCharm

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, subprocess, sh

My file structure is:

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── costSensitiveClassifier.py
└── vowpal.sh
|
├── data
│   ├── output
│   │   ├── cost
|   |   |_______openCostClassifier.dat
|   |   |
```

And within `costSensitiveClassifier.py`, I essentially am trying to run a script called `vowpal.sh` that does some manipulations on `openCostClassifer.dat` and outputs some files into the same folder as that file.

The code within `costSensitiveClassifier.py` is:

```
import subprocess
print "Starting cost sensitive predictions using batch script\n"
subprocess.call("../../vowpal.sh")
print "Ending predictions"
```

And the code within `vowpal.sh` is:

```
# !/bin/bash
vw --csoaa 24 data/output/cost/openCostClassifier.dat -f data/output/cost/csoaa.model
vw -t -i data/output/cost/csoaa.model data/output/cost/openCostClassifier.dat -p data/output/cost/csoaa.predict
```

Note, I am running `costSensitiveClassifier.py` within pyCharm, and my error is:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "/Users/me/Documents/university/anonymous/src/main/costSensitiveClassifier.py", line 324, in <module>
    subprocess.call("../../vowpal.sh")
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/Users/me/anaconda/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1335, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error
```

Here is the [vowpal wabbit tutorial](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Cost-Sensitive-One-Against-All-%28csoaa%29-multi-class-example).

Comment: Does your `vowpal.sh` script have a [shebang](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165808/should-i-use-a-shebang-with-bash-scripts) `#!/bin/bash` as the first line?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati `# !/bin/bash` is not acceptable. The first two characters of your script must be exactly `#!`. You can have `#!/bin/bash` or `#! /bin/bash`, just not what you wrote.

Comment: Wow that was the answer..(sigh)

Comment: Note, now the problem comes in what is running in my bash script: 
`vw (./io_buf.h:123): can't open: data/output/cost/csoaa.modelerrno = No such file or directory`. This is because my python script is not waiting for the bash script I called to finish running and output these new files e.g. `csoaa.model`