# Called subprocess doesn't execute bash script in sequence

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, subprocess

Following on from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38750718/subprocess-call-not-working-from-pycharm) which relates to a different problem, I thought I would frame in terms of this problem.

**NOTE**: I have tried all versions of `subprocess.Popen()`, `communicate()`, `wait()`, such as:

```
vowpal = subprocess.Popen('../../vowpal.sh',shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
vowpal.communicate()
print vowpal.returncode
```

I have a file structure like this:

```
├── src
│   ├── main
│   │   ├── costSensitiveClassifier.py
└── vowpal.sh
|
├── data
│   ├── output
│   │   ├── cost
|   |   |_______openCostClassifier.dat
|   |   |
```

And within `costSensitiveClassifier.py`, I essentially am trying to run a script called `vowpal.sh` that does some manipulations on `openCostClassifer.dat` and outputs some files into the same folder as that file.

The code within costSensitiveClassifier.py is:

```
import subprocess
print "Starting cost sensitive predictions using batch script\n"
subprocess.call("../../vowpal.sh")
print "Ending predictions"
```

And the code within vowpal.sh is:

```
# !/bin/bash
vw --csoaa 24 data/output/cost/openCostClassifier.dat -f data/output/cost/csoaa.model
vw -t -i data/output/cost/csoaa.model data/output/cost/openCostClassifier.dat -p data/output/cost/csoaa.predict
```

The issue is always that the second line of the bash script needs there to be something called `csoaa.model` to be output first (see line 1 of the bash script), and once finished, the second line should run which uses that file to output `csoaa.predict`. However, this is not the case and I get when running the python file I get in my error code related to the bash script:

```
vw (./io_buf.h:123): can't open: data/output/cost/csoaa.modelerrno = No such file or directory
```

I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180914/pause-resume-a-python-script-in-middle) but not sure if it is what I need (should I adapt the sleep to be the expected time for the bash script to finish and create the files I need to work on?).

Comment: It seems like you need a work flow management library like [snakemake](https://bitbucket.org/snakemake/snakemake/wiki/Home) or [ruffus](http://www.ruffus.org.uk/)

Comment: Also your error suggests your script is looking for `csoaa.modelerrno` not `csoaa.model`

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem in vowpal. It tries to create an error file, which it can't. One of the reasons could be that the directory "data/output/cost/" doesn't exist.

That's what was causing same error for me.