# issue with bash when running in crontab

Tags: bash, ubuntu

Hope somebody can point me in the right direction in solving this problem. I have this bash with if statement.

```
checkPID=(MySQL queries to count columns)

if [[ $checkPID -eq 1 ]]
then
echo "PID already exist, running update queries instead"

(MySQL update queries here)

else

echo "PID does not exist, running insert queries"

(MySQL insert queries here)

fi
```

When I run this bash script on the command line everything works as expected, but when I automate this via crontab it doesn't follow the if condition regardless of the value of the checkPID variable.

Comment: How do you run it, via file, or directly in your term ?

Comment: when I test it i run with the bash command. when I want to automate it i run it via crontab

Comment: via a script file or inline in crontab ?

Comment: Standard crontab troubleshooting: does anything in it depend on the environment (working directory, `PATH`, other environment variables, etc)? Have you captured output & errors from it (e.g. by adding something like `>>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` to the crontab command, then checking the file for indications of what's going wrong)?

Comment: I suggest that you do at the start of your cron-script a `set -x; echo $BASH_VERSION`. This will not only show you all the statements being executed, but you can also verify that `bash` is indeed used. And, don't forget that in your `bash` command line you have a different environment than with cron.

Comment: Also, you didn't post your crontab, and don't provide any meaningful error description. How can you expect help here?

Comment: Hi, Thank you guys for your replies. @user1934428 my crontab please see below.

*/10 * * * * sh /home/servo/scripts/slavereport.sh

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson did what you suggested I got this error message on the log
/home/servo/scripts/slavereport.sh: 34: /home/servo/scripts/slavereport.sh: [[: not found

Comment: @AYSMAN That error suggests the script is running under dash (which doesn't support `[[ ]]` conditionals) instead of bash (which does). Does the script have a bash [shebang line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25165808/should-i-use-a-shebang-with-bash-scripts) (i.e. `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, and *not* `#!/bin/sh`)? Also, in the crontab entry, do you run it directly or use something like the `sh` command to run it?

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson,
Thank you for this. I changed the crontab entry from "sh" to "bash" and this made the script run as expected. Adding this >>/tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1 om crontab absolutely helped. Cheers!

Comment: @AYSMAN It's generally better to set a proper shebang in the script, make sure it has execute permission set, and then run it directly (without either the `sh` or `bash` commands). That way, the script itself controls what it runs in, which is where the control really should be.

Comment: Hi @GordonDavisson  so you mean this "#!/bin/bash" on top of the script file?

Comment: Don't put crucial information, such as the content of your crontab, in a comment. Write it into your question. BTW, you aren't running your script as bash in this way, but by sh. Also, if this is the **complete** crontab, I don't see where you set up your environment. This makes me wonder: Did you ever check the stderr from your script when executed by cron????

Comment: @AYSMAN Yes, that's the shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

Your crontab line uses `dash` (`/bin/sh`) instead of `bash`.

```
*/10 * * * * sh /home/servo/scripts/slavereport.sh –
change to:
*/10 * * * * bash /home/servo/scripts/slavereport.sh –
```

Since you are using `bash` operations, remember to put `#!/bin/bash` as the first line in the script.

Fixing either of these should also resolve the issue. It isn't required to do both.